# Vim Powerline is at top of window instead of bottom

Tags: plugin-powerline

I just installed Powerline for the first time and the Powerline bar shows up at the top of my Vim window instead of at the bottom.

This is both on MacVim and on terminal Vim.

Running OS X 10.10 and iTerm2, with Vim version 7.4.258.

Powerline was installed with Vundle as such:

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
```

[image: Powerline at top instead of bottom. Works fine otherwise.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not Powerline, that is Airline. The plugin has a feature that displays a fake tabline at the top of the screen and that's what you see.

How to enable that feature is probably explained somewhere in `:help airline`.

Also, you need `set laststatus=2` in your `vimrc` to enable the *actual* statusline for all windows.

Comment: The advantage of using these worthless gimmicks is exactly to not have to spend time customizing the statusline by simply enabling/disabling features in the plugin. But since we're criticizing these plugins let's be honest here: there's even no need for a statusline to work in vim, so even the comment "read `:h 'statusline'` is unnecessary ;)

Comment: 1. "read :h 'statusline'" implies that the other person wants a custom statusline and shows that there's no need for a plugin for having one. 2. Judging by the number of powerline/airline questions here, on #vim and elsewhere, the shortcut doesn't seem that short.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not quite satisfied with this community's reception towards my question. This is already a stagnant community as it is (rather it should be growing).

That out of the way, I specifically installed powerline from here: https://github.com/powerline/powerline.

Comment: @romainl: I did not see an existing tag for Powerline, and searching for Powerline only returned one or two other hits on this SE. And if you're not convinced it isn't Airline, I've tried `:help airline` and it says "Sorry, no help for airline."

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Sorry, I'm just used to be more hospitable community on /r/Vim. I guess this SE isn't immune to the overall worshipping of top commenters either—Math.SE is similar. I've added the Vundle command I used to install Lokaltog/powerline in my OP. I've already checked if it's my .vimrc and it isn't; I completely renamed it so my vim can't find it and the Powerline bar is still at the top of the window, unfortunately. I'm running stock vim from homebrew, and I installed Powerline through Vundle. Seems standard enough that this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Romainl is our resident 'tough love vimmer' =P. Nevertheless, the advice he gave you is solid. If you don't have airline installed, then it appears that powerline (or another plugin) has modified your tabline, which always appears at the top. Your status line is currently hidden and can be shown with `set laststatus=2`

Comment: 1. What you see at the top of the window is **NOT** the powerline statusline. It is something else: a fake tabline showing the buffers in the current tab page. 2. To see the actual Powerline tabline, you *must* have `set laststatus` in your `vimrc`. 3. The fake tabline feature was introduced by Airline, maybe it is now in Powerline… who knows? 4. Which one do you use: `lokaltog/powerline` or `powerline/powerline`?

Comment: @MattBoehm Thanks for the context—it's appreciated. The top bar I was seeing turned out to be from a package called `buftabline`. Setting `laststatus` worked as you and romainl suggested—thanks!

Comment: @romainl Setting `laststatus` worked to enable the statusbar as you said. The tabline came from another package called `bufabline`. And I'm using `lokaltog/powerline`. Thanks again!